# SPCalendarView not working properly in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, visual-web-part, sharepoint-calendar

I have Created a Custom Calendar webpart using `SPCalendarView` type. After adding this webpart to my page it is not displaying any events and the navigation buttons(two arrow buttons) for changing month/week/day and links for changing the month/week/day view is not working.

The Simple Code I used :

```
public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        SPCalendarView cal;
        private AudienceLoader audienceLoader = AudienceLoader.GetAudienceLoader();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            cal = new SPCalendarView();
            cal.Visible = true;
            cal.EnableViewState = true;
            cal.DataSource = GetItems();
            cal.DataBind();
            this.Controls.Add(cal);
        }

    private SPCalendarItemCollection GetItems()
    {
       var items = new SPCalendarItemCollection();
        SPCalendarItem item = null;
        item = new SPCalendarItem();

        item.ItemID = "Select";
        item.Title = "First calendar item";
        item.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        item.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        item.hasEndDate = true;
        item.DisplayFormUrl = "/News";
        item.Location = "USA";
        item.Description = "This is the first test item in the calendar rollup";
        item.IsAllDayEvent = false;
        item.IsRecurrence = false;
        item.CalendarType = Convert.ToInt32(SPCalendarType.Gregorian);
        items.Add(item);
        return items;
    }
}
```

ScreenShot: 
[image]

The above circled controls are not working. Do anyone know the reason?
And I also want the link for creating event in each grid(like in OOTB Calendar Webpart).

**EDIT :**
   But, if I disable V4rendering `cal.EnableV4Rendering= false;` then old calendar view is displayed and everything works perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You should inherit your web part from `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart`, not from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart` it was inherited by default.

This inheritance appends all needed javascript code and js-functions calls, and your SPCalendarView will work propertly.

So, your `VisualWebPart.cs` should look like this:

```
namespace TestCalendar.VisualWebPart1
{
   [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
   public class VisualWebPart1 :  Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart 
   {
       //bla-bla-bla generated code
   }
}
```

And look here: it's a very good answer just about your problem:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f10155d3-8ac6-4d8c-8c33-b4d5dbae6e2d/spcalendarview-in-sharepoint-2010-placed-on-custom-aspx-form-does-not-respond-to-any-actions?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious